# Windows 10 (1803) share folder in home network with password

Tags: windows-10, passwords, file-sharing, sharing

As my long title implies, I have a windows 10 (version 1803) and a folder in it that I want to share.
I want to use a password so every time the other PC in my network wants to use the files he needs to enter the password (just for security).

In Control Panel > Network & Sharing Center > Change Advanced Sharing Settings > All Networks > I've checked "turn on password protected sharing"

And indeed I can see the folder in the network, and it asks me for a password.

But where do i configure what password I want to use?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Super User. Does it ask you for a _user name_ and password?

Comment: yes. User name is the PC name?

Comment: I think it is looking for a valid username and password pair that works locally on the serving PC

Comment: but the serving PC (the one where the shared folder is) has a user name, but not a password.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have run into the problem that you cannot access a remote share using an account with no password. The serving PC has a user account with no password and this cannot be used to access a shared folder without some workarounds.

However, you actually *want* a password to be requested and so this account is no good to you. Create a user account on the sharing PC that *does* have a password and share the folder adding this user with read permissions at least.

[image: screenshot of share dialog]

This will allow the user to add a username and password pair that works which is what you want. However, I don't think that this will stop the user from saving the credentials so that she does not need to type them every time.